# Identify a mobile phone user using an http header in PHP

Tags: php, mobile, browser, user-agent

Kind of an odd question but still wanted to check.Is there a way in which I can uniquely identify a mobile phone user who has visited my website using the http header.Getting the mobile phone or IMEI of a user is an impossible thing , but is there any work around to identify a mobile phone user who visit my website or from the user agent details?

Any ideas?

Comment: look at [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.server.php) there you get some information like `HTTP_USER_AGENT` or `REMOTE_ADDR` which is unique likely for some hours/days

Answer (score 0):

I think not only php but combination with javascript will do the job. On page load you can get the screen width by using screen.width and then pass it to php file.

Hope it helps.